# When should I split a GUI class into several classes?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I'm working on what's basically my first GUI program in Java and it's been working well for me so far. Everything runs smoothly, however I want to make sure I use and understand solid programming principles.

For my GUI class I have about 300 lines of code (which I've come to understand is pretty small). I've been using SWT and this GUI one window for now. I have four tab items that each contain a different set of widgets for use. I intend on having a class for each tab to take care of their respective back end requirements.

As I've searched existing questions I've found the Single responsibility principle referenced on several occasions. To my understanding, one window per class would fit this principle. When (if ever) would I break a GUI into multiple classes outside of multiple windows?

Comment: Multiple views inside a window. For example, the the score view, weapons view, etc. in a game could all be individual view classes that get populated in a single window. Other, more obvious, examples would be the components used like custom buttons and so forth.

Comment: I can understand the example for custom buttons. For different views, it would be to reduce unnecessary communication right? For example, score view doesn't need to know any of the properties a weapon has.

Comment: Sort of. It's not reducing *unnecessary* communication because, unless you purposely put unnecessary communication in somewhere, it's all necessary. What it will do is allow you to keep a view to a single responsibility - for example, present the weapons to the user. So yes, you want to decouple your components/classes as much as possible; it they're not related or necessarily dependent then separate their concerns. Looking into the Observer pattern and its offspring like MVC would give some insight on decomposing your GUI designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design principle are guidelines for writing good code. `Single responsibility principle` says we should have only single source of change for a class.

1. How do we know what is the source of change in a class ?
2. What can change in a class ?

Answers to these questions lies with the team directly in touch with the end users. For this it is important to reach to the team interacting with the client as soon as possible with a basic simple design. It is quite obvious , we will be asked to add more new features or add new requirements.

The process above will let us know what is the set of responsibilities that our class is performing is changing. We must put those set of behaviors in separate class(s). Now our existing class should communicate with the newly created classes via. Abstractions. This is `dependency inversion`. Now our class no longer is dependent upon the entities which change or which can potentially change with high probability. In the abstractions only the behaviors needed by the our old class are put. Implementation details are put in newly created concrete classes which extend the Abstraction class we have created.

From the very beginning, trying to figure out all the responsibilities and putting them in separate classes even when (they may never possibly change) will make the code scattered.

Large classes are verbose. They are not browsable, they have high risk of getting affected with changes un intentionally.

Comment: When creating a product it can be a process of creating a simple design then refining it based off of client requirements. Then the existing design can be expanded and possibly refactored to meet client requirements. Trying to design each aspect upfront can make the code hard to work with. When a class is large it can be good to separate aspects of it to lower the risk of unintentional change. Am I understanding what you said correctly?

Comment: @Hranz yes you are right. Guidelines are important and should be followed to avoid writing bad code. Design principles are guidelines for us, the coders. But while following them we should apply them wisely. We should learn not to over apply these to an extent that the design becomes hard to understand. Design your code keeping in mind about what principles teaches us but same time not doing over engineering. Observe the change and then doing continuous refactoring as per what we see changes in the requirements is best.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your specific question on when you would want to break out stuff into a separate class:
Let's assume you write an address book. You would probably want to present a contact's details in various places of the application. Or present multiple contacts at once. This would be accomplished by writing a separate class, like `ContactDetailsPanel`.

In general, most of the usual patterns apply to GUI classes as well: don't repeat yourself, single responsibility, and so on. One pattern I would like to point out when writing GUI code is [MVC: Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It's basically about separating business logic, presentation, and data.

You might want to take a look at what kind of things get separate classes in SWT, too.